# Navigation components/screens have to be unmounted or not?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying different ways to build a complex app with react-navigation and
I am wondering if my app components have to be unmounted or not.

Does the fact that in react-navigation DrawerNavigator and TabNavigator, components are mounted and putted in memory when inactives, may cause some performance troubles??

I don't know If just switch from screen to screen letting them mounted is the best way to navigate?

Let's say my app tree is like :

-- app

```
---- stack1
     ---- stack1page1
     ---- stack1page2
     ---- stack1page3

---- stack2
     ---- stack2page1
     ---- stack2page2
     ---- stack2page3

---- stack3
     ---- stack3page1

---- stack4
     ---- stack4page1
     ---- stack4page2
```

At first I created a materialBottomTabNavigator for switching within all the stacks (stack1, stack2, stack3 and stack4).
But when I visited all the stacks, there are all mounted, and I am asking myself, is it a problem???

So now I'm doing it with another approch, trying to unmount every stack when I switch to another, and now I'm asking myself, is it a problem???

Lol, please help me with nice arguments :)

react-native: 0.57.8
react-navigation: 3.1.5

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

When you use StackNavigator or TabNavigator, which component is unmounted totally depends on the fact a user is leaving it or coming back to it.

Consider the following scenario as explained in the docs of React-navigation -

> Consider a stack navigator with screens A and B. After navigating to A, its componentDidMount is called. When pushing B, its componentDidMount is also called, but A remains mounted on the stack and its componentWillUnmount is therefore not called.
>
> When going back from B to A, componentWillUnmount of B is called, but componentDidMount of A is not because A remained mounted the whole time.

I suggest you to read the Navigation Lifecycle on the docs. Here's the link -

> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answer.

My question was about TabNavigator and DrawerNavigator and not about StackNavigator, wich is very different.
I already know that component B is mounted and unmounted when you switch from A to B and when you come back to A.
I'm using some StackNavigators and I don't have problem with it.

The fact is, you can't always use StackNavigators with complex apps.

So :

I'd like to know if with **Tab or Drawer Navigators**, we need to **unmount components** when we switch from a screen to another or if it's ok that all the screens that compose my navigator are all mounted.

**Example**

TabNavigator
--- stack1
--- stack2
--- stack3

Here you entering in the app on stack1, you switch to stack2, then you switch to stack3.
With TabNavigator default config, all the stacks (or here, components inside stacks) will be mounted.

Is it a performance problem??
Do I have to unmount my component when I'm switching from stack1 to stack2 for example ??